# Move navbar-brand to center when navbar collapsed in bootstrap 5

Tags: css, navbar, bootstrap-5

How can I move navbar Brand to the center when navbar collapsed (stay on left/right side when navbar expands)in bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy Solution**

You can solve this problem very easily by adding an empty DIV after the brand element:

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
    <div></div>
```

**Why does this work?**

The navbar uses display flex with [justify-content: space-between](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content). The extra DIV creates 3 columns rather than 2 and with the brand in the center.

**Snippet**

Run the snippet and resize to trigger the breakpoint. The brand is in the center when collapsed but otherwise appears on the left.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
    
    <div></div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```